# Reset counter at line break

Tags: string, vb.net, line-breaks

I'm developing a VB program, and I'm analyzing a set of strings. 
These string are 6 numbers on a row separated by a space.

> 5 1.667e-02 5.08 4.98 0.01112

I want to count the spaces and at line break reset the counter

```
If Mid(line, g, 1) = " " Then
    Dim h As integer
    h = h + 1  
End If
```

How do I do this? Is it possible on VB?

Comment: What's the actual endgame here? Are you trying to determine the number of spaces after the last line break in each `String`? Please provide some context.

Comment: This is probably VBA (or VB6) and not VB.NET

Comment: The usual way to handle this in VB is to use the split() function.

Comment: The main goal is to count the spaces if the counter is equal to (let's say 3) then read that number.

Answer (score 1):

To count the occurence of a char you could use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/linq/).

```
Dim str As String = "5 1.667e-02 5.08 4.98 0.01112"
Dim h As Integer = str.Count(Function(c) c = " "c)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myStringSplitLine
    Dim myStringSplit
    Dim myStringResult As String = ""
    Dim myString As String = "5 1.667e-02 5.08 4.98 0.01112" & vbCrLf & "5 1.667e-02 5.08 4.98 0.01112"
    myStringSplitLine = myString.Split(vbCrLf)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    For j = 0 To UBound(myStringSplitLine)
        myStringSplit = myStringSplitLine(j).Split(" ")
        For i = 0 To UBound(myStringSplit)

            If i = UBound(myStringSplit) Then
                myStringResult = myStringResult & myStringSplit(i)
            Else
                myStringResult = myStringResult & myStringSplit(i) & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next
        MessageBox.Show("Count:" & i - 1 & " " & vbCrLf & myStringResult)
        myStringResult = ""
    Next
End Sub
```